# In Gradle Kotlin script (kts) DSL, how to make a function usable in other scripts?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Assuming that I have a Kotlin script under `buildSrc`:

```kotlin
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/greet.gradle.kts
fun Project.greet(greeting: String) {
    println("$greeting from ${this.name}")
}
```

I want the function `greet` enabled in another script:

```kotlin
apply(from = "greet.gradle.kts")
apply(plugin = "greet")

greet("me")
```

but none of the `apply works`, I still got the following error:

```
 Unresolved reference: greet
```

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To make a function usable in other scripts in Gradle Kotlin script (kts) DSL, you need to define the function in a separate Kotlin file inside the buildSrc/src/main/kotlin directory. This directory is treated as an included build by Gradle, which means it can contain its own dependencies and can be used to share code across multiple projects.

Here is how you can do it:

Create a new Kotlin file in the buildSrc/src/main/kotlin directory. Let's call it Greeting.kt.

```
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Greeting.kt
package com.example

fun Project.greet(greeting: String) {
   println("$greeting from ${this.name}")
}
```

In your build.gradle.kts file, you can now import and use the greet function.

```
// build.gradle.kts
import com.example.greet

greet("me")
```

This will print me from rootProjectName to the console.

Please note that the buildSrc directory must be at the same level as your build.gradle.kts file. If it's not, you will need to move it.

Also, remember to refresh your Gradle project after adding new files to buildSrc. This can be done in most IDEs by clicking on the "Refresh all Gradle projects" button in the Gradle tool window.

Comment: Unfortunately the kt file won't be able to use other class extensions like dependencies { implementation { ...}}. I can only use a kts file, not a kt file